# Make the axis.text half bold in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I need to make the text half bold as in the sample.
[image: What I have]

[image: What I need]

What should I change in the theme??

This is my code:

```
#Visualiation
my_theme <-   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 16, color = "grey30"),
                    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16, color = "grey30"),
                    axis.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
                    legend.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
                    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
                    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
                    panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "gray", size = 0.1))

ggplot(df_athlete, aes(x=Height,y = reorder(Year,Year), fill = Gender, group = interaction(Year, Gender))) +
  geom_density_ridges(alpha=0.75, rel_min_height=0.05) + 
  labs(title = "Height Distribution of Olympic Athletes", subtitle = "Data from 2001 to 2022",
       x = "Height", y = "Olympic Year", caption = "Source: athlete_events.csv") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FFA190", "steelblue1"), labels = c("Female", "Male")) +
  theme_ridges(center = TRUE) + xlim(150,200) + my_theme
```

I tried face=400 it didn't work(

Comment: What does half bold mean?

Comment: I see all components are either "all bold" or "not at all bold", please explain what you mean by that.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think by half bold, they want a different font weight. Like using weight 400 instead of 900 or whatever default bold font weight is.

Comment: itidk where to add weight....

Comment: Per the ```element_text()``` documentation, the possible arguments to give for ```face``` are "plain", "italic", "bold", or "bold.italic", so changeing the weight of bold font won't be possible there. Another option may be to use plotmath with ```bold()```, although I can't find any ways to specify weight within that function

Comment: It sounds like you need to select a fontface with the weight you want and assign that to the text you want half bold. e.g. you might use Roboto Regular 400 most places, but Roboto Medium 500 for the part you want heavier weight. https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto